# Angular2 reverse Directive lookup

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is there a way to lookup a directive instance only based upon the reference to a DOM element?

In Angular1.x you could have such a behaviour by using [JQLite's "Controller" function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods), for which the controller was actually returned (even based upon optional type argument).

To be more specific, I want to be able to identify an element by its position, using [document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) and retrieve to which Directive *instance* this belongs...

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild()`

```
<my-comp #someRef someDirective></my-comp>

...
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('someRef', {read: SomeDirective}) someRef:SomeDirective;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.someRef);
  }
}
```

By default `@ViewChild()` returns `ElementRef` for plain HTML tags or the component instance of a component. With `{read: SomeType}` you can specify what you want to get returned from `@ViewChild()`.

You can also use `exportAs` like

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'my-dir',
  ...
  exportAs: 'myDirective'
})
class MyDirective {
}
```

and then use it like

```
<my-comp my-dir #someRef="myDirective">
```

and then get hold of it in the component using

```
@ViewChild('someRef') someRef:MyDirective;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input; however, I don't fully see how I can change the "string" selector for a template variable to actually use a reference to an already retrieved element, for instance retrieved by document.getElementById or document.elementFromPoint :-)

Comment: You can't. At least there us no official way.

Comment: I feared something in those lines. So far, my "best" idea is to "extend" the DOM element by adding the reference to the instance there. Feels... illigal, but might be the only possibility. Another similar approach would be to build a hashtable of DOM elements of a specific type and retrieving them based upon their native element...